# Can i call a vf page as popup from a custom link button from a standard sf page

Tags: salesforce

I want to show a popup of list of cases without parentid and allow to select usign checkbox and the selected cases are added up in a related list. This popup would be availabe on clicking of link button

First question would be can i call a vf page as popup from a standard page? The rest i guess i can hande it in the VF page

Thanks
Prady

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you create a link button for the object in whose page layout the link will reside. As a source for the link button choose "Visual force page" and choose a page. Keep in mind that the vf page MUST use standardController for the same object (with or without extensions) or it will not show up in the list. Choose to show the page in a new window and later place the link button on the page layout.